Upgrading WixStandardBootstrapperApplication Wix v3 to v4
I'm attempting to update the following Wix Bootstrapper project from V3 to V4 but after the update the V4 setup.exe never displays UI (only the splash screen):
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs" xmlns:bal="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/bal">
  <?include Variables.wxi?>

  <Bundle Name="$(var.BundleName)" Version="$(var.BundleVersion)" Manufacturer="Blah" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)"
    DisableModify="no" DisableRemove="no"
    SplashScreenSourceFile="Splash.bmp">

    <BootstrapperApplication>
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseUrl=""
                                              LogoFile="Logo.jpg"
                                              LocalizationFile="Localization.wxl" 
                                              Theme="hyperlinkLicense"
                                              ThemeFile="Theme.xml"/>

      <!-- Background image used by Theme.xml -->
      <Payload SourceFile="Background.jpg" />
    </BootstrapperApplication>

    <Chain>
      <!-- This will check for and install .Net 4.8 downloading the installer from the Web -->
      <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx48Web" />
      <MsiPackage Id="Blah" SourceFile="$(var.Blah.setup.TargetPath)" Compressed="yes" Vital="yes" Visible="no" />
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>

The log file contains the following error messages:

Error 0x80070490: Failed to find image id.
Error 0x80070490: Failed to parse theme images.
Error 0x80070490: Failed to parse theme.
Error 0x80070490: Failed to load theme from path: C:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Local\Temp{51D1CE6B-27D7-4A96-BD15-D0D2A4A633E9}.ba\thm.xml
Error 0x80070490: Failed to initialize data in bootstrapper application.

Our own project does not reference a 'thm.xml' and we explicitly specify both a theme and localization file attributes so I'm not sure why it's specifically looking for this file.
As soon as the 'ThemeFile="Theme.xml"' attribute is added the installer UI breaks. Without this the installer UI has no issue showing the default UI for the 'hyperlinkLicense'.
How is this suppose to work in V4? I cannot find any V4 examples using custom themes with a 'WixStandardBootstrapperApplication' tag.
NOTE: I didn't write the original V3 installer so this is rather new to me.
UPDATE: If I rename the 'ThemeFile.xml' to 'thm.xml' then the error messages changes to the following:

Error 0x80070002: Failed to probe for loc file: thm.wxl in path: C:\Users\SIMON~1.KEN\AppData\Local\Temp{995B1599-1BDB-4A23-9B8F-7FE135EF291F}.ba\
Error 0x80070002: Failed to initialize data in bootstrapper application.

Now its looking for a localization file called 'thm.wxl' which implies its successfully loading the 'thm.xml' file.
Even if I rename 'Localization.wxl' -> 'Thm.wxl' the installer will still fail to find the resource. I can see the value being added to the 'wix build' command line output. What am I missing?
For reference the V3 bootstapper content looked like this (the reset of the code seems unchanged as far as I can tell):
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.HyperlinkLicense">
  <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication SuppressOptionsUI="yes"
                                          LicenseUrl=""
                                          LocalizationFile="Localization.wxl"
                                          LogoFile="Logo.jpg"
                                          ThemeFile="Theme.xml"/>

  <!-- Background image used by Theme.xml -->
  <Payload SourceFile="Background.jpg" />
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>


I substituted the contents of the official V4 themes into my own theme file and then installer progressed and displayed UI so, as suggested, the contents of the our 'Theme.xml' is invalid. I made some minor modifications based on the V4 theme but no luck. How should a user go about validating a theme file?

Yeah, I eventually worked out that a bunch of tags and properties have changed between versions though I cannot find these changes documented but  the  documentation for V4 seems like its still in preview stage. However that was only the start of the issues I was seeing so I gave up. Is answering a question as 'Too hard' acceptable?
